# decrypting md5 hashes in python

Tags: python

So in the code which I am working on now, there is a section that generates local key using md5. The code that generates the string is as follows:

```
data_encoded = serialize(results)
data_encoded = data_encoded.encode('base64')
thishex = md5(str(checkdate)+licensing_secret_key)
thishash = thishex.hexdigest()
data_encoded = thishash+data_encoded
data_encoded = data_encoded[::-1]
thathex = md5(data_encoded+licensing_secret_key)
thathash = thathex.hexdigest()
data_encoded = data_encoded+ thathash
data_encoded = textwrap.fill(data_encoded,70)
results["localkey"] = data_encoded
print data_encoded
```

where `results` is a dictionary that contains values, `checkdate` is the result of time.time().

Now I try to decrypt this as follows:

```
tmp = len(localkey) - 32
localdata = localkey[:tmp]
md5hash = localkey[tmp:]
localtemphex = md5(localdata+licensing_secret_key)
localtemphash = localtemphex.hexdigest()
print md5hash
print localtemphash
```

where `localkey` is the previously generates string (`results["localkey"] = data_encoded`), licensing_secret_key is a string given at the beginning.

The print command shows mis-matched strings. Is there anything I am missing out here?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Based on the comments, here's more information about what I am trying to achieve. Say, someone purchases a license key - every time he/she uses the product, the script will try to authenticate against the server to check for the validity of the license. Now, for some reason, if the server can't be polled, there needs to be a mechanism wherein there exists a local key (which is generated at the time of the last remote check and stored locally) which would be valid, say for a couple of days.

Hence, the code in essence is trying to check if the last local key generated is valid on not. I didn't know how else to check for it except maybe reversing the hash, which now I know (from the comment) isn't possible. (Essentially I was trying to emulate the model followed by WHMCS's license checker add-on)

(PS: Sorry if this sounds too noobish-just getting the hang of coding in general and Python in particular).

Comment: Note: a hash is one way... e.g. **not encryption**. Not to say you couldn't be finding collisions, but you wouldn't be "decrypting" a hash.

Comment: @MarkBaker - ok. Thing is I don't know PHP and I am just beginning to find my way around Python and this is something I am trying to achieve. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: There ISN'T a way to do it in any language.... that's the whole point of hashing functions

Comment: A hash function by definition given a unique input _should_ produce a unique output, in a one way irreversible transform. Reality however shows us that certain inputs will produce the same result, certain hashes such as MD5 can be made to easily produce such collisions at complexities far less than brute force. Hence why MD5 should not be used for anything remotely close to security.

Comment: @Mgetz - Thank you for clearing that up. I guess I'll have to find other ways to check validity of keys.

Comment: @i.h4d35 you can use a hash function to check the validity of keys, but this isn't the way to do it. If you're going to use a hash to check the validity of the key then when the customer buys the key you store the hash of the key + salt, and the salt in the database. When they verify their key with you you rehash the key + salt and compare to the stored hash.

Comment: *A hash function by definition given a unique input should produce a unique output*  Nonsense. It should produce the same output consistently. Having a fixed size output guarantees there will be collisions, it's a logical impossibility to compress infinitely many possible inputs to a finite number of possible outputs.

Comment: You need to clarify what you're trying to accomplish.  As comments have suggested, you can't reverse a hash.  If you need something reversible, you probably want to use something like aes using the licensing secret key as your key, but that would depend on your goal rather than your current approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the question and thought I'd share it here. Hope I don't draw too much ire from the community. So, the problem was, there would always be a mismatch between the `md5hash` and the `localtemphash` variables. After re-reading the code hundreds of times, and checking out the logical flow of the PHP code and echo the output of every line, I figured out the answer. The encode would add newlines and these too would be hashed by the md5 algorithm (I didn't know that). Thanks to all the people who pointed me in the direction, especially MGetz. So for those who want the code, here it is:

```
                        data_encoded = serialize(results)
                        data_encoded = data_encoded.replace("\n","")
                        data_encoded = data_encoded.replace(" ","")
                        print "\n\n Serialized\n"+data_encoded+"\n\n"
                        data_encoded = data_encoded.encode('base64')
                        data_encoded = data_encoded.replace("\n","")
                        data_encoded = data_encoded.replace(" ","")
                        print "\n\n ENCODED\n"+data_encoded+"\n\n"
                        thishex = md5(str(checkdate)+licensing_secret_key)
                        thishash = thishex.hexdigest()
                        data_encoded = thishash+data_encoded
                        data_encoded = data_encoded.replace("\n","")
                        data_encoded = data_encoded.replace(" ","")
                        print "\n\n MD5ed\n"+data_encoded+"\n\n"
                        data_encoded = data_encoded[::-1]
                        data_encoded = data_encoded.replace("\n","")
                        data_encoded = data_encoded.replace(" ","")
                        print "\n\n Rverserd\n"+data_encoded+"\n\n"
                        thathex = md5(data_encoded+licensing_secret_key)
                        thathash = thathex.hexdigest()
                        print "\n\n\n THAT HASH\n"+thathash+"\n\n"

                        data_encoded = data_encoded+ thathash
                        data_encoded = data_encoded.replace("\n","")
                        data_encoded = data_encoded.replace(" ","")
                        print "\n\n MD5ed\n"+data_encoded+"\n\n"
                        data_encoded = textwrap.fill(data_encoded,70)
```

I used some wrong terms in the question like **decrypting** which wasn't what I was trying to do - now I know the difference. The solution was to remove the newlines and the whitespaces and the checking part worked.

Thanks everyone..

Answer (score 3):

Try this script.  I estimate it would take half of a second to run*

````
__all__ = ('brute_force', 'crack', 'make_library')
encryptions = ['md5', 'sha1', 'sha224', 'sha256', 'sha384', 'sha512']

import hashlib
from random import randint
from os import _exit, mkdir
from sys import stdout, argv
from atexit import register
from time import sleep
from os import fsync, rename

class brute_force:
    def __init__(self, mot_de_passe_a_trouver='', nombre_de_carateres_depart = 1, caracteres_max=42):
        '''
        Librairie de recherche de mots de passes encrypte
        Library for decrypting encrypted passwords

        Encryptions:
        md5, sha1, sha224, sha256, sha384, sha512
        '''
        self.ascii_debut = 32
        self.ascii_fin = 126
        self.nombre_de_mots = 0
        self.compteur = 1
        self.puissances = []
        self.dernier_mot_de_passe_hashe = ''
        self.dernier_mot_de_passe = ''
        self.nombre_de_carateres = nombre_de_carateres_depart
        self.mot_de_passe_a_trouver = mot_de_passe_a_trouver

        while (self.compteur <= caracteres_max):
            self.puissances.append(int(((self.ascii_fin-self.ascii_debut)**(self.compteur))*2.5))#you could change the "2.5" but you risk fail many words if you reduce it and if you increment it you will waste time
            self.compteur += 1
        self.compteur = 1

    def __len__(self):
        return self.nombre_de_mots

    def set_char(self, nombre_de_caracteres=int()):
        '''a shortcut to change number of chars by generated words'''
        if not nombre_de_caracteres:
            self.nombre_de_carateres = nombre_de_caracteres
        return self.nombre_de_carateres

    def one_search(self, encryption):
        '''Generate one random password and returns true if found'''
        self.new()
        self.encode(encryption)
        if (self.mot_de_passe_a_trouver == self.dernier_mot_de_passe_hashe):
            return True
        return False

    def new(self):
        '''
        Creer un mot de passe possible
        Create a new random word
        '''
        self.dernier_mot_de_passe = ''
        for lettre in range(self.nombre_de_carateres):
            self.dernier_mot_de_passe = self.dernier_mot_de_passe + chr(randint(self.ascii_debut, self.ascii_fin))
        self.nombre_de_mots += 1
        return self.dernier_mot_de_passe

    def generate(self, encryption, nombre_de_carateres=int()):
        '''
        could be used to make library of passwords with hash to avoid wasting time by rehashing at every crack
        example:
        >>> pycracker.brute_force().generate("md5", 5)#5 is the lenght of desired password "md5" is the encryption you want
        ['D0!Zc', '807bacbbe4c2fea3723e9f1858fd484c']#return a list with generated pass and hashed generated pass
        '''
        if nombre_de_carateres:
            self.nombre_de_carateres = nombre_de_carateres
        return [self.new(), self.encode(encryption)]


    def encode(self, encryption):
        '''md5, sha1, sha224, sha256, sha384, sha512'''
        self.dernier_mot_de_passe_hashe = getattr(hashlib, encryption)(self.dernier_mot_de_passe).hexdigest()
        return self.dernier_mot_de_passe_hashe



class brute_writer:
    def __init__(self, encryption, nombre_de_carateres_depart=int(1)):
        '''
        A tiny class to generate random passwords 
        and hash it to write it out in files using pickle
        '''
        self.brute = brute_force()
        self.encryption = encryption.lower()
        self.brute.nombre_de_caracteres = nombre_de_carateres_depart
        self.tout_mots = []
        self.compteur = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self.brute.nombre_de_mots

    def __str__(self):
        return self.brute.nombre_de_mots

    def __del__(self):
        '''Save before any exit'''
        self.on_save()

    def set_char(self, nombre_de_caracteres = 0):
        if not nombre_de_caracteres:
            self.brute.nombre_de_caracteres = nombre_de_caracteres

    def on_save(self):
        '''Save the pass'''
        try:
            mkdir('library')
        except OSError:
            print("\n[*] dir already created")
        file = open("library/dict%sc%i.crack" % (self.encryption, self.brute.nombre_de_caracteres), "a")
        file.write("\n".join(self.tout_mots))
        file.flush()
        fsync(file.fileno())
        file.close()
        self.tout_mots = []

    def make(self, encryption):
        ''''''
        self.compteur += 1
        self.tout_mots.append("\t".join(self.brute.generate(encryption)))



def make_dict(encryption, nombre_de_carateres_depart=1, display=True):
    '''
    generate random passwords and hash it 
    to write it out in files using module
    '''
    m = brute_writer(encryption, nombre_de_carateres_depart)
    if encryption not in ['md5', 'sha1', 'sha224', 'sha256', 'sha384', 'sha512']:
        print("Encryption not found")
        _exit(0)
    while (True):
        try:
            if (m.brute.puissances[m.brute.nombre_de_carateres-1] == m.brute.nombre_de_mots):
                    m.brute.nombre_de_carateres += 1
            if (m.compteur >= 500000):
                #do a backup every x times
                m.on_save()
                m.compteur = 0
                m.tout_mots = []
            m.make(encryption)
            if display:
                stdout.write("\rGenerating: %i" % len(m))
                stdout.flush()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("\nKeyboard interrupt")
            m.on_save()
            sleep(5)

def crack(encryption, hash_password, display=True):
    '''
    return the password from a hash if found
    >>> import pycracker
    >>> print pycracker.crack("md5", "49f68a5c8493ec2c0bf489821c21fc3b")
    Tested: 3500 passwords searching now with 2 chars
    hi
    '''
    brute = brute_force(hash_password)
    if encryption not in ['md5', 'sha1', 'sha224', 'sha256', 'sha384', 'sha512']:
        print("Encryption not found")
        _exit(0)
    try:
        while (True):
            if (brute.puissances[brute.nombre_de_carateres-1] == brute.nombre_de_mots):
                    brute.nombre_de_carateres += 1
            if (brute.one_search(encryption)):
                print
                return brute.dernier_mot_de_passe
            if display:
                stdout.write("\rTested: %d passwords searching now with %d chars" % (len(brute), brute.nombre_de_carateres))
                stdout.flush()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nKeyboard Interrupt")
        exit()

def crack_with_dict(dict_name, to_crack):
     try:
          file = open(dict_name, "r")
     except IOError:
          print("File not found: %s" % dict_name)
          exit()
     for ligne in file:
          if ligne[ligne.find("\t")+1:].replace("\n", "") == to_crack:
                return ligne[:ligne.find("\t")]
     return ''

def crack_with_file(file_name, encryption, hash_pass):
    brute = brute_force()
    encryption = encryption.lower()
    if encryption not in ['md5', 'sha1', 'sha224', 'sha256', 'sha384', 'sha512']:
        print("Encryption not found")
        _exit(0)
    try:
        _file = open(file_name, "r")
    except IOError:
        return ("File: %s not found" % file_name)
    _file.seek(0)
    print("Cracking...")
    for ligne in _file:
        brute.dernier_mot_de_passe = ligne.replace("\n", "")
        if brute.encode(encryption) == hash_pass:
            return ligne.replace("\n", "")
    print "Not found"

def quitter():
    print("Exitted before found any correspondance")
    _exit(0)

def main():
    '''
    usage:
    [mou@mou pycracker]$ python pycracker.py sha1 1 c22b5f9178342609428d6f51b2c5af4c0bde6a42
    Tested: 1032 passwords searching now with 2 chars
    Found: 
    hi
    [mou@mou pycracker]$
    '''
    register(quitter)
    __help__ = ('''
craken.py: basic help
Usage: python {0} [-c Crack a hash]
                  [-g generate a dict of passwords, encryption as 2nd arguement]
                  [-h display this help]
                  [-f crack a hash using plain text file
                       use -d if you used -g on the file]
                  [-d crack a hash using a dictionary file (use -g to make one)
                    no encryptions arguements needed]
Example:
    python {0} -c md5 "c268120ce3918b1264fe2c05143b5c4b"
                      or
    python {0} -f passwords.txt md5 "c268120ce3918b1264fe2c05143b5c4b"
                      or
    python {0} -d dictmd5c1.crack '61bad16b91c29a757f6b36c21a065197'
    '''.format(argv[0]))
    try:
        if (argv[1].lower() == '-c'):
            try:
                print("\nFound: %s" % crack(argv[2].lower(), argv[3]))
            except IndexError:
                print("More arguements needed\n%s" % __help__)
        elif (argv[1].lower() == '-g'):
            try:
                make_dict(argv[2].lower())
            except IndexError:
                print("More arguements needed\n%s" % __help__)
        elif (argv[1].lower() == '-f'):
            try:
                print("Found: %s" % crack_with_file(argv[2], argv[3].lower(), argv[4]))
            except IndexError:
                print(__help__)
        elif argv[1].lower() == '-d':
             try:
                  print("Found: %s" % crack_with_dict(argv[2], argv[3]))
             except IndexError:
                  print(__help__)
        elif (argv[1].lower() == '-h'):
            print(__help__)
        else:
            print("try: python %s -h" % argv[0])
    except IndexError:
        choix = input("1. Generate a dictionary\n2. Crack a password\n3. Crack a password using a file\n4. Crack a hash using a dictionary file\n: ")
        if (choix == 1):
            make_dict(raw_input("Encryption\nmd5, sha1, sha224, sha256, sha384, sha512\n: "))
        elif (choix == 2):
            print("Found: %s" % crack(raw_input("Encryption\nmd5, sha1, sha224, sha256, sha384, sha512\n: "), raw_input("Data to crack: ")))
        elif (choix == 3):
            print("Found: %s" % crack_with_file(raw_input("File name: "), raw_input("Encryption to crack: ").lower(), raw_input("Hash to crack: ")))
        else:
            print("Found: %s" % crack_with_dict(raw_input("File name: "), raw_input("Hash to crack: ")))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("""
                                              ,MD5
                                            ,o
== THE CRAKEN ==                           :o
                   _....._                  `:o
                 .'       ``-.                \o
                /  _      _   \                \o
               :  /*\    /*\   )                ;o
               |  \_/    \_/   /        lulz     ;o
               (       U      /                 ;o
                \  (\_____/) /                  /o
                 \   \_m_/  (                  /o
                  \         (                ,o:
                  )          \,           .o;o'           ,o'o'o.
                ./          /\o;o,,,,,;o;o;''         _,-o,-'''-o:o.
 .sha384      ./o./)        \    'o'o'o''         _,-'o,o'         oSHA1
 o           ./o./ /       .o \.              __,-o o,o'
 \o.       ,/o /  /o/)     | o o'-..____,,-o'o o_o-'
 `o:o...-o,o-' ,o,/ |     \   'o.o_o_o_o,o--''
 .,  ``o-o'  ,.oo/   'o /\.o`.
 `o`o-....o'o,-'   /o /   \o \.                       ,o..         o
sha512`o-o.o--    /o /      \o.o--..          ,,,o-o'o.--o:o:o,,..:oSHA256
                 (oo(          `--o.o`o---o'o'o,o,-'''        o'o'o
                  \ o\              ``-o-o''''
   ,-o;osha224     \o \
  /o/               )o )
 (o(               /o / 
  \o\.       ...-o'o /
    \o`o`-o'o o,o,--'
      ```o--''' """)
    main()
    _exit(0)
````

<sub>[ [credit](https://github.com/mouuff/craken/blob/master/pycracker.py) ]</sub>

<sup>* on a super computer</sup>